# Record IFrames only in Android

Tags: android, video, camera, mediarecorder

My app requires to record a video to capture the IFrames only (and not the P/B frames).

I am making use of the Media Recorder to capture the video (Not using cameraX as I need HEVC and camerax is recording in H.264).
The 'MediaRecorder.MetricsConstants.VIDEO_IFRAME_INTERVAL' is set to 1, by default - hence I get an IFrame every 1 sec and the rest of the frames in a second are 'P'. I need the VIDEO_IFRAME_INTERVAL constant to be set to 0, inorder to make all the frames 'I'. I have tried different ways to set it. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried setting it this way:

```
mRecorder.metrics.deepCopy().apply {
    this.putInt(MediaRecorder.MetricsConstants.VIDEO_IFRAME_INTERVAL, 0)
}
```

Even if I set it to '2', '5' or '10' it doesn't seem to be having an effect.

Comment: I don't use Android SDK but... **(1)** See if [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) is more useful than MediaRecorder for having customised settings (_eg:_ keyframe intervals). Or does it need CameraX to work? **(2)** An HEVC key frame is also just an HEIF image. Maybe just take constant multiple photos in HEIF format whenever your app "records" then later package into MP4.

Comment: Will give it a shot with MediaCodec. Was trying the best to make it work with MediaRecorder itself else I will also have to use a Muxer. 
Thank you for your reply.